# Openswan on EC2 VPC

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, vpn, ipsec, vpc

I am working on establishing a VPN tunnel between our VPC on Amazon and a client network , the client uses public IP addresses behind their firewall and requested that our servers in the VPC to use public IPs also.

The purpose of the connection is that our application server and their application server to be able to communicate.

Here s what the topology looks like:

107.x.x.x <--> 107.y.y.y <--> AWS InternetGateway <--> Internet <--> 213.a.a.a <-->213.b.b.b

where:

```
107.x.x.x: Our Application server (internal ip 10.0.0.10)
107.y.y.y: Our Openswan server (internal ip 10.0.0.11)
213.a.a.a: The costumer VPN endpoint ip 
213.b.b.b: The customer Application Server
```

We managed to bring the tunnel up, but whenever we try to ping 213.b.b.b we get **Destination Host Unreachable**

here is the ipsec.conf:

```
left=10.0.0.10
leftsubnet=107.x.x.x/32
leftid=107.y.y.y
leftsourceip=107.y.y.y
right=213.a.a.a
rightid=10.9.5.34
rightsubnet=213.b.b.b/32
authby=secret
keyingtries=3
rekey=no
keyexchange=ike
ikelifetime=86400s
phase2alg=3DES-MD5;modp1024
forceencaps=yes
pfs=no
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

you probably need to "source route" the pings.  Try ping -I {LAN IP of sender} 213.b.b.b

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your openswan server has src/dest checks as disabled (use the EC2 console to accomplish that) and that your VPC's routing table contains the following route line
destination 213.b.b.b route via "openswan server" (in addition to the default 0.0.0.0/0 via the internet gateway)